# php/mysql - Calculations from match results (goals)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have a database with all the soccer matches from a season, and i want to do some simple calculations with the results. This is wat the table looks like:

```
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+--+
| HomeTeam | AwayTeam | HomeTeamGoals | AwayTeamGoals |  |
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+--+
| team1    | team2    |             3 |             1 |  |
| team3    | team4    |             1 |             2 |  |
| team1    | team3    |             4 |             4 |  |
| team4    | team2    |             0 |             1 |  |
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+--+
```

Now I want to calculate 4 things for each team:
- total goals scored in home games
- total goals scored in away games
- total goals against in home games
- total goals against in away games

With this query I get all the information for the homegames back correctly:

```
SELECT HomeTeam, SUM(HomeTeamGoals) as HomeTeamGoals, SUM(AwayTeamGoals) as AwayTeamGoals
FROM games
GROUP BY HomeTeam
```

But how do I now get the info for the away games (from the same query)?

Outcome should be as follows with the data from the table above:

```
+-------+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+
| team  | home for | home against | away for | away against |
+-------+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+
| team1 |        7 |            5 |        0 |            0 |
| team2 |        0 |            0 |        2 |            3 |
| team3 |        1 |            2 |        4 |            4 |
| team4 |        0 |            1 |        2 |            1 |
+-------+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: there is not a FTHG or FTAH field in the table you have shared. The query doesn't match with the table

Comment: @LelioFaieta My bad, is fixed in the query now.

Comment: show your expected result in table structure

Comment: @fa06 added to original.

Comment: @Awesom-o, you can check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with union all:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a1bbfadd62ed68808605a9e7767870d

```
select hometeam, sum(HomeTeamGoals) as homefor,sum(AwayTeamGoals) as homeagainst, 0 as awayfor, 0 as awayagainst from tablename
group by hometeam

union all

select AwayTeam, 0,0, sum(HomeTeamGoals) as awayfor, sum(AwayTeamGoals) as awayagainst from tablename
group by AwayTeam
```

Output:

```
hometeam    homefor homeagainst awayfor awayagainst
team1       7       5            0      0
team4       0       1            0      0
team2       0       0            3      2
team3       0       0            4      4
```

Comment: Hi Fa06! I get all the right data back so that's perfect! Thanks for that. Got one issue with printing the data, it now shows a list with all the teams twice, one list with alle the home-data and one with all the away-data. Is that normal with the way we did this now?

Comment: Here is the code that i use to print the data: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qg3k-5u8t

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

input:

```
create table goals(
homeTeam varchar(10),
awayTeam varchar(10),
homeTeamGoals tinyint,
awayTeamGoals tinyint
);
insert into goals values('team1','team2',3,1),('team3','team4',1,2),('team1','team3',4,4),('team4','team2',0,1);
```

[image]

Output:

```
select totalTeams.team as hometeam,
  case when a.totalHomeGoals IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.totalHomeGoals END as totalHomeGoals,
  case when a.totalHomeAgainstGoals IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.totalHomeAgainstGoals END as totalHomeAgainstGoals,
  case when b.totalAwayGoals IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.totalAwayGoals END as totalAwayGoals,
  case when b.totalAwayAgainstGoals IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.totalAwayAgainstGoals END as totalAwayAgainstGoals
      from (select homeTeam as team from goals union select awayTeam from goals) as totalTeams 
      left join (select homeTeam as team, sum(homeTeamGoals) as totalHomeGoals,sum(awayTeamGoals) as totalHomeAgainstGoals from goals group by hometeam) as a on totalTeams.team=a.team
      left join (select awayTeam as team,sum(awayTeamGoals) as totalAwayGoals,sum(homeTeamGoals) as totalAwayAgainstGoals from goals group by awayTeam) as b on totalTeams.team=b.team 
      order by hometeam ;
```

[image]